# Can my condenser mic be plugged into Linux Ubuntu directly for use?

Tags: sound, alsa, microphone, audacity

I want to know if anyone call tell me If the **Rockville RCM03 Pro Condenser Microphone** can be plugged in the sound card and used directly with **Audacity** (recording editing software) and on **Linux Ubuntu 18.04**.

I am looking forward to buying the microphone because I see it for a great price and it has fantastic reviews.  I would like to know if any one of you has had success using this microphone or others without using an audio interface box.  I have not found an audio interface box that is stated as compatible with Linux anyway.
In the features list for the microphone, it does say. “Power Requirements: 48V DC phantom power or computer sound card (can connect to the phantom power channel of your mixer or can connect to your laptop or computer)”  However, I want to be sure that I am interpreting this properly and that I will not have a surprise and or difficutly.  For example, will my computer provide the “phantom power” that the device needs?  Do all computers do that?  Does this happen at the sound card or within in the sound software on Linux Ubuntu?  I  found that Linux uses ALSA (Advanced Linux Sound Architecture), but I know nothing about its ability to support the microphone I listed above or any other audio device or interface (with the exception of the USB microphone that I own and that is quite unsophisticated).
In answering this question, if you can please educate me a little about anything pertinent to this topic.  I really want to move forward.  The first step is getting the correct audio components that will work well with Linux Ubuntu and Audacity.  I’d like to use your experience to get the setup right the first time.  Thank You.

Note: I am running Linux Ubuntu on my Dell personal computer. It is installed along-side Windows 10 in a dual boot configuration. I will not be using Windows 10 at all! I WILL be running Audacity on LInux Ubuntu.

Comment: It's up to your hardware, not Ubuntu. Does it work w/ Audacity in Windows? Then it will work w/ Audacity in Linux. If you click [edit] and provide the Service Tag of that Dell, we can look up the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can't plug **any** microphone into audacity. You can plug it into a sound card. If your sound card supports phantom power, you're good to go. If not, you need a phantom power source. If you only have the on board standard sound card, it probably does not provide phantom power, and likely does not provide a balanced input either.

If you buy such a microphone, you should probably look into an external audio card that either supports phantom power, or at least XLR inputs.

Phantom power sources does not need to be compatible with Linux. They're a hardware device that sits between your audio card and the microphone. Commonly, they use a 9VDC battery to power the microphone.

See [this eBay search](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=phantom+power&_sacat=0) for such power supplies. They have one side you connect to your microphone, and one that connects to your sound card.

So what you have to find out:

1. Can your sound card supply phantom power?
2. Is your sound card supported by Linux?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I haven't been able to find out if my sound card supplies phantom power.  I do believe my sound card is supported by Linux however, because I have recorded many things from my unsophisticated USB microphone.  I am willing to purchase one of the eBay power supplies that you so nicely pointed me to.  I greatly appreciate that.  That way I will get the phantom power.  The mic comes with the XLR to XLR cable and the XLR to 3.5 mm connector.  So it seems if I purchase the power supply, based on what you wrote, I will be ok.  Do you agree?

Comment: A USB microphone does not use your audio card. It essentially has its own sound card, communicating via USB. But in general, you will be fine with what you suggest, yes.

Comment: I think I just confirmed that Linux does support my sound card.  I plugged a microphone headset into the sound card (via a 3.5 mm connection) and did a recording.  Everything sounded fine when I did the playback via VLC.  So now it's just the phantom power for the condenser mic.  Again, thank you.  Understanding before I make purchases saves time and grief.

Answer (score 0):

I am using an electret microphone with my OptiPlex 755 computer. It works very well with Audacity and with EchoLink, an amateur radio app. I am not sure by any means if my system's sound card provides phantom power; however, it must be working as the microphone works perfectly well with both apps.

Comment: I have the Dell Optiplex 7010.  I haven't been able to find out anything about the standard sound card that comes with it.  I found specs, but it doesn't go to that level of detail.  I looked at both the manuals for your Electret and the mic I want to purchase (Rockville) and I did not recognize a difference largely because I don't know what to look for.  I am considering going the @vidario route and buy a power supply for the mic.  That way I know that I have the phantom power.  I guess I will control the volume, etc via Audacity.